# Month selectable date time picker control

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Is there any way in C# forms to show only months and years selectable when we dropdown the date time picker control? I do not want the days to be selectable.

I do not want to use numeric up down. for selecting month and year.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: then you have to make check this : `dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;`

Comment: As I mentioned in question I want to use drop down box for easy selection. I do not want to use up down arrows

Answer (score 0):

try this link using jquery plugin:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

```
    $j('dDatetime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y/m/d A g:i',
        formatTime: 'A g:i',
    });
```